# Does fractional freezing always happen in mixtures that are prone to it?

Tags: phase-transition, freezing

Let's assume that we have a mixture that is prone to fractional freezing, such as water with table salt, or water with alcohol.

If we place the mixture in a sufficiently cold environment, will we always have fractional freezing, with ice forming from only the water? Or are there further conditions which have to be met? Are there cases where we will get a homogenous ice block of the mixture, as opposed to a separation?

As some background, I remember reading somewhere that it only happens when the conditions are "right", but don't remember what these "right" conditions are. Also, in the kitchen, I have observed that at least for stock, what I get is frozen cubes, not pure water ice floating on top of a cooled layer of concentrated stock.

Comment: Haha, I was just searching Physics.SE with the intention of asking this myself (although I would have made it more specific to the original question).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but if the temperature is below the freezing point for both components of the solution, and the solution cools down fast enough, there will not be fractional freezing.
Also, some mixtures can form an "eutectic system", which has a freezing point that is lower than that of both its components. In such a system there will also be no fractional freezing.